# How do I reduce the interest I'm paying on unused student loan?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, student-loan

I am studying at a US university, on a student loan from a UK company - funds are paid directly to the university.

The loan provider already disbursed the loan amount to my university's finaid division, but now I have received a tuition waiver so I don't require all of it.

When I told the loan provider this, they said:

> You will need to inform your school's financial aid office to return any unused funds to us. However, please note that refunds take 3 - 6 months to be received as this is a US regulation. You will be charged interest for this time.

What is my best course of action here? Is there a way to reduce the money I'm charged for? I'm not even sure what these *regulations* are.

Comment: Will the school disburse the funds to you instead of returning them? You could then make a payment to the UK lender directly.

Comment: @DStanley I thought so too. But the rules are that the tuition payment is done directly to the school.

Comment: But if they send the school the entire loan amount (which is more than the total tuition), you'll have a credit balance with the school. Can they not give you the remaining balance so you can pay the lender? I know of no US financial regulation that would withhold funds for months. Maybe a week or so, but not months.